# Passing this as prop in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have some components that use a lot of functions so sometimes to avoid having todo `<Component func1={func1} func2={func2} ... />` which looks ugly I do `<Component component={this} />` when the same functions are called in the component. So this should obviously be slower but how much really? Is this a terrible coding-pattern? I suppose I could also just create a new obj with the used functions and pass that in instead.

EDIT: I belive the best solution is to create a function called: 

`getFuncs(component) 
{ 
  return { func1: ..., func2: ... } 
}`

In the reactClass and then call: `<Component funcs={this.getFuncs(this)} />`

Comment: I believe it to more descriptive and clear than ugly. Also maintaining parent and children this instance could be quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
   const componentProps = {
     func1: this.func1,
     func2: this.func2
   };
   <Component {...componentProps} />
```